# HQL ArrayList returning more than one type of class

Tags: java, list, hibernate, arraylist

This is not a "problem" because everything is working correctly, but it is really mind–boggling that it is working correctly and I can't find the answer.

So I have some simple hibernate HQL Query:

```
 List<Comment> commentList = session.createQuery("select c, u from Comment as c, User as u where c.postRef.id = :post_id").setParameter("post_id", postId).getResultList();
```

When it runs, and I look at the debugger it returns the `commentList` that looks like this:

```
 - commentList - "ArrayList<E>",
   - elementData - Object[10]
     - [0] - Object[2]
         - [0] Comment
         - [1] User
     - [1] - null
     - [2] - null ... ( etc, to the end it's null)
```

And I just cannot understand it, how is it possible that in this `ArrayList<E>` there are two types of objects? Both `Comment` and `User` in one `ArrayList`, I can assume that this is creating `ArrayList` of objects or something, but then how is this possible that it returns `ArrayList<Object>` properly to `List<Comment>` without throwing any exception? And then my method is also of return type `public List<Comment>`, and I return this exact `commentList`, and everything works perfectly fine.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item returned by `getResultList()` is an array of type Object[], since the query returns two objects - one Comment and one User.

The reason this works on the compile level is [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens): The type of a parameterized generic such as List is not compiled into the byte code. At the level of byte code, it's just a List, and `List<Comment>` is not distinguishable from `List<Object[]>`.

You should receive a warning from your compiler that the assignment

```
List<Comment> commentList = session.createQuery("select c, u from Comment as c, User as u where c.postRef.id = :post_id").setParameter("post_id", postId).getResultList();
```

is not type safe, i.e. the compiler cannot guarantee that what `getResultList()` returns is indeed a List of Comments (and, in your example, it actually isn't).

During runtime, the assignment works due to type erasure, but what you have in your `List`, are `Object[]` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your query return two Object so you have to cast each one with the correct Object.

Your List should be like this :

```
List<Object[]> commentList = ...;
//---^^^^^^----------------your list get an array of two Objects

List<Comment> listComment = new ArrayList<>();
List<User> listUser = new ArrayList<>();

for (Object[] result : commentList){
     Comment comment = (Comment) result[0];//First object is Comment
     User user = (User) result[1]);//Second object is User

     listComment.add(comment);
     listUser.add(user);
}
```

---

I don't know about your Entity design but i think a user can have a List of comments, so you can make it better then this.